# Angular 2 file saver excel file

Tags: angular, filesaver.js

I have developed sample POC to save excel file delivered by backend api. In UI I am using Angular 2 with filesaver.js.

Now when i try to call "saveAs" function of file-saver, chrome is giving following error

TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_file_saver**.saveAs is not a function

Here is my package.json

> "file-saver": "^1.3.3",

Here is my angular-cli.json

> "scripts": ["../node_modules/file-saver/FileSaver.js"],

here is my angular2 service component

```
exportFile(){
    this._http.get(this.url,{responseType : ResponseContentType.Blob})
        .map( (response) => {
            let blob = response.blob();
            console.log('Received excel data....');
            return{
                data : new Blob([blob],{type : 'application/vnd.ms-excel'}),
                filename : 'test.xls'
            }
        })
        .subscribe(
            (res)=>{
                console.log('Exporting excel file');
                FileSaver.saveAs(res.data,res.filename);
            }
        )
}
```

At the top i have imported file saver as follow

> import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';

Whole project is located on github

[Angular2 Export Demo](https://github.com/pritspatel/NG2ExcelExportImportDemo.git)

Comment: Based on the error a `saveAs` function does not exist on the imported object. Have you tried importing `saveAs` directly? `import * as saveAs from 'file-saver';` and then use like this `saveAs(res.data, res.filename)`

Comment: Trying that giving me an error like "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature."

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't have the import in your  angular-cli.json if it is in your package.json
Try to delete the line `"../node_modules/file-saver/FileSaver.js"` from the angular-cli, then delete the file-saver directory from your node_modules and then do a `npm install` or better a `yarn install`.